# How do I change the text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code. The code always appends some text to an old one. But I dont want that the text is attached to the old text. Instead, I want that it replaces the old text.

Here is the code line:

```
$("#werkstatt").append("Text");
```

How can I do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: $("#werkstatt").text("Text");

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method.

```
$("#werkstatt").empty().append("Text");
```

or simply you should use `.text()` method.

```
$("#werkstatt").text("Text");
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept answer if you consider that is what expected.